# Java Gett variable from within a loop in another class?

Tags: java

I was wondering how it is possible to get the value of a variable/boolean that is inside of a loop in a different class.

I would have a variable in one class and want get that in another one:

Class1:

```
public void mainLoop()
{
while(!Display.isCloseRequested)
{
    frames++
    if(frames == 200)
    {
        key = 5
        run = false;
    }

    if(frames == 400)
    {
        key = 10
        run = true;
    }
}
}
```

and in my other Class2 I want to acess the changed varibles:

```
public Class2()
{
public void printVariables(int key)
{
    if(key == 5) { System.out.println("KEY 5"); }
    if(key == 10) { System.out.println("KEY 10"); }
    if(run == false) { System.out.println("RUN FALSE"); }
    if(run == true) { System.out.println("RUN TRUE"); }
}
}
```

How?

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Your loop will never terminate.

Comment: It's just an example, the actual loop is way bigger and much more complicated - but just for you I've edited my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it as a parameter to the method:

```
public Class2()
{
    public void printVariables(int key)
    {
        if(key == 5) { System.out.println("KEY 5"); }
        if(key == 10) { System.out.println("KEY 10"); }
        if(run == false) { System.out.println("RUN FALSE"); }
        if(run == true) { System.out.println("RUN TRUE"); }
    }
}
```

And then call that method with an instance of the class:

```
public void mainLoop()
{
    Class2 cls2 = new Class2();
    while(someCondition == true)
    {
        frames++
        if(frames == 200)
        {
            key = 5
            run = false;
        }

        if(frames == 400)
        {
            key = 10
            run = true;
        }
        cls2.printVariables(key);
    }
}
```

Or, if you can, make the method static and call it statically (i.e. `Class2.printVariables(key)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly.. I believe I can make it static too even though I'm still not exactly sure what I'm doing to my variable when I'm setting it to static - could you by any changce elaborate how I need to do it with a static variable and what the disadvantages might be?

Comment: Glad to help. As for the static - you don't need to change any variable, just your method (`printVariables`). It'll simply mean you don't need an instance in memory of `Class2` every time you use it (no need to do `new Class2`). Here you might be using it once in your code but if you'll want to use it elsewhere, you won't need to instantiate `Class2`. I suggest you google and familiarize yourself with the subject a bit more.

Comment: Thanks.. well I guess having it static will not suffice since I want to use it multiple times and change the variable from time to time.. I stubled upon a little problem though.. first I thought it works as I want but it seems to have some issues, I've edited my question so you can see what I've done and where the problem is, hope you can help me out some more - what I'm trying to achieve is really crucial for the entire program to work properly..

Comment: First of all, you did not "update" your question, you've done a complete 180 and changed it! People will be much less inclined to help you if you revoke your accepted answer mark, and then edit your question to a whole *new* question!! Now, as for this brand new question, I'm not really sure what the problem is, mainly because your code makes no sense: `Input` is a method of `Class2`, yet you refer to it as if it were a method of `Class1` like `pressE`. You'll need to do `movCam.input(1)` instead or better explain your new question / scenario. Also, please follow naming conventions.

Comment: I'm sorry to have offended you.. didn't notice that I have deleted the rest and as for the revoked acceptance, I just thought since my problem is still not yet completely answered I better uncheck this otherwise the question might not be noticed by others because they think it has been aswered already. I didn't really change my question it's just that your answer wasn't enough to completely solve the problem so I was being more specific. Sorry to cause confusion and disconfort..

Comment: As for the Input.. it's correct as I wrote it don't worry I know my code.. This whole thing is a bit more complicated so I kept it short (I removed the line to not confuse others).. the Input refers to a bunch of methods in Class1 - Class2 actually extends another Class which enables to interact with Class2 through the Input method over yet another Class that interacts with my Transform matrix - it's very complicated that's why I didn't mention everything.. as for this question the Input method shouldn't matter.. again sorry for even more confusion.. hope you still can and want to help me..

Comment: Again, you're asking a different question. You should have just opened a new one, since the the code is fundamentally 100% different. The way things stand no one beside me is likely to see this question. Had you asked a new one ,your odds would have been much better. Anyway, by trying to make it simple, you've made it much more complicated. I'm looking at the latest revision of your code and now I understand even less. you never call `input` method but you ask how come it always returns (I'm assuming prints?!) true. Currently, it is impossible to understand what this new problem is.

Comment: Well, okay.. I'll open a new question for this one and try to change my question back to it's original form, then you'll get your cookie back and everyones happy..